# MySQL query in Supertest returning {sql, bindings} instead of results

Tags: mysql, node.js, jestjs, supertest

I'm running supertest + jest against a route that queries a mysql db, run locally. Testing through insomnia returns the correct information, but none of my db queries return correct values when using supertest.

```
// test.js

import request from 'supertest';
import db from '../database';
import app from './app';

describe('/', () => {
  test('should return db results', async () => {

    const mock = jest.spyOn(db, 'query');

    const response = await request(app).get(`/`)

    console.log(response.error);
    expect(dbMock).toBeCalled();
    expect(response.status).toBe(200);
  });
});
```

```
// route (excerpt from app.js)

import returnUserInfo from './returnUserInfo';

app.get(
  '/',
  returnUserInfo
);
```

```
// returnUserInfo.js

import db from '../database';

export default async function returnUserInfo(req, res, next) {
  const sql = 'select `userInfo` from `users` where `email` = ?';
  const bindings = ['test'];
  try {
    const data = await db.query(sql, bindings);
    if (data.length !== 1) {
      throw new Error(`Invalid ${Object.keys(data)}`);
    }
    return res.json(data[0]);
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
}
```

```
// database.js

import { PoolConnection } from 'mysql';

const db = new PoolConnection(
  {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'foobar',
    database: 'db',
    connectionLimit: 100,
  },
  false,
);

export default db;
```

As mentioned before, testing with postman/insomnia returns the correct result...
When testing with supertest and logging the error:

```
Error: Invalid sql,bindings
```

Comment: Your spyOn const is named mock while you check the expected call on dbMock. Are you sure this is not a typo?

Comment: thanks @happyhardik, that was a typo when transferring to SO. The real issue was a manual mock of the database module which was blocking any actual query from hitting the db. Thanks again, though!

Answer (score 0):

It appears there had been a node_module manual mock for the mysql db which was overriding all calls to the database and simply returning

```
{ sql, bindings }
```

Note to self: when things don't make sense...check that they're supposed to be making sense.

Comment: You can select your answer to have solved the problem, so the question can be closed.